# C:: how: run a error check that a string is too long in a loop

Tags: c, string, loops, input

Struggling with some homework and for the life of me, I cannot figure this out. 
pseudo logic would be

```
 printf("Enter a string\n");
```

then run loop to check if the string is longer than 10 chars
if not re-prompt to enter a string less than 10 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask a specific question about your problem, and provide us with your attempt so far. Otherwise, we'll have to make assumptions about your understanding of C, and such assumptions might seem offensive.

A user can't be expected to enter a '\0' character using their keyboard, so this idea that a "string" might come from stdin seems silly. How many bytes must you read before the user presses this '\0' key? At the very most, ten. Write a loop that starts with `x = 0;` and continues while `x < 10`. The loop should break when `getchar() == '\0'`. Outside of the loop, test x. If x reaches 10, then the loop ended before '\0' was entered; Prompt for the user to enter a new string.

Perhaps your teacher wants you to use some other character as a terminal character, and store the result into an array (in which case the input isn't really a *string*, because a '\0' isn't relevant to the end). Once you have the above program written, you can adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, depending on the overall goal.

```
char input[11];

if (scanf("%10s", input) != 1)
    ...error...
...here, the string is not longer than 10 characters, and contains no white space...
```

If you're determined to allow them to enter more characters and then complain, or if you need them to be able to enter spaces, then:

```
char input[4096];

while (1)
{
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == 0)
        break;  // EOF or error
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    if (len > 0)
        input[--len] = '\0';   // Zap newline
    if (len <= 10)
        break;
 }
```

This prompts, reads, truncates, validates in a loop.  You might need to think about how you distinguish between EOF or error and valid input when you exit the loop.  That is most easily done if the code is actually in a function which is passed the buffer to use for the input:

```
int prompt_for_string(const char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        if (fgets(buffer, buflen, stdin) == 0)
            return EOF;
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
            buffer[--len] = '\0';
        if (len <= 10)
            return len;
    }
    return EOF;
}
```

If you were really determined, you could write an input loop with `getchar()` or one of its relatives in place of `fgets()` or `scanf()`.  It's fiddlier, and doesn't provide any obvious benefit.

Comment: In `int prompt_for_string(const char *prompt, char buffer, size_t buflen)`, buffer is not a suitable type to pass to fgets as the first parameter, or strlen, or to use a pointer subscript operator on.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Thanks for pointing out the typo — I'd omitted the `*` in `char *buffer`.

Comment: In addition, the code that corresponds to the comment `// Zap newline` doesn't verify that a newline exists at input[--len]. What happens if input[--len] != '\n', for example when `len == buflen - 1` (preceding the prefix decrement)? This code would discard a byte of input. I suggest something like: `size_t len = strcspn(buffer, "\n"); buffer[len] = '\0';`

Comment: I've updated the code (differently from your suggestion) to address the issue.  I'm not convinced it matters; if you pass in a 4 KiB buffer and are going to ignore it if the value is longer than 10, the fact that buffer[4094] is or is not a newline is barely going to matter, and you have more reading to do to get to the next newline if you are worried about it.  We could also use `fputs(prompt, stdout)` instead of `printf("%s", prompt);`, and there are other changes that could be made.